# Correct Usage of wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a program to understand wait() and notify() methods. But when I run the program it hangs and nothing happens. Basically I want one thread (ThreadDemo) to complete its execution (display its output) thereafter other thread should display its output (ThreadDemo2).

As wait and notify requires the use of same object I have created common class LogicClass.

Can you please point out what is the problem in my code? I have to use these concepts in my project.

[Program Link](http://ideone.com/hE5rn)

Comment: @all i have found the solution .I was calling display() method in both the thread run method.so deleting this question.

Comment: This is a good example on when its useful to use a debugger. It also worth trying to make the example as simple as possible as that way a) you are more likely to understand it and b) someone is likely to read it.

Comment: @peter i would surely follow your advice.I had tried to debug the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code, I noted at least two problems:

- Your main function does not wait for the child threads to join and so will exit. Use Thread::join.
- You never call `show()` function that includes the `notifyAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that non-daemon threads will not exit when the main thread exits.

I'd recommend using java.util.concurrent package if at all possible.  It makes multithreading less error prone.  You are missing for example a missed notification guard that can cause eternal waiting.  If you were to use a latch it would solve that problem.

** EDIT

Sorry I should say your existing missed notification guard (value in LogicClass) can have cases where it doesn't function correctly - the while loops before the wait or notify aren't sufficient to guarantee which thread "wins the race" to the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment earlier about making the code shorter while still demonstrating the same behaviour. You can see one thread is running `show`, the other `display`

```
class ThreadMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final LogicClass lg = new LogicClass(true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("In threadDemo run method");
        lg.show(10);
      }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("In thread2 run method");
        lg.display(5);
      }
    }).start();
    System.out.println("Hi, in main");
  }
}


class LogicClass {
  boolean value;

  public LogicClass(boolean value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  synchronized void show(int a) {
    if (value) {
      for (; a != 0; a--)
        System.out.println("This Output should come first");
      value = false;
      notifyAll();
    }
  }

  synchronized void display(int a) {
    while (value) {
      try {
        this.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    for (; a != 0; a--)
      System.out.println("This should come later");
  }
}
```